# Two updates in one MySQL query

Tags: mysql, updates

How can I perform the following two updates in only one MySQL query?

```
$query = "UPDATE news SET main = 1 WHERE id = '$id'";
mysqli_query($this->db_conn, $query);
$query = "UPDATE news SET main = 0 WHERE id <> '$id'";
mysqli_query($this->db_conn, $query);
```

Only one row should be set to `1` while the rest of them should be set to `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
UPDATE news SET main = CASE
    WHEN id = '$id' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END
```

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. Now the problem is that I don't know how. I have to study a little more of the CASE sentence for MySQL. I don't understand it.

Comment: Case statements in SQL are tricky. You're not alone in having to look them up!